# Why is there no highlight for questions with negative-scored answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, highlighting

While browsing questions on Stack Exchange sites, the questions with answers are highlighted. But there is no highlight on the main page for answers that have a negative score.

I suggest to highlight questions where all answers have negative votes since other users may then be encouraged to answer the question. Usually most of the people leave the questions that are already answered, but there's no guarantee at present that they have been answered well.

So why not highlight questions whose answers have negative votes?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Azik now clarified my question

Comment: There is a reason that most answers have negative scores: they are not good answers. Why in the world would we want to call attention to them by highlighting them?

Comment: @CodyGray if we highlight it would force new users to answer it,as i mentioned most of the users leave questions since it has already answered

Comment: @ValamburiNadan, you want to highlight or not?

Comment: @Azik i suggest highlighting for answers with - votes ,it doesn't mean i need ,its just a suggestion

Comment: @ValamburiNadan, if we highlight those negatively voted answers, then as you mentioned, `the new users leave questions since it has already answered`, so it is good to highlight the positive scored answers

Comment: Wait, do you perhaps think the `2` is the number of votes? It is not, it is the number of *answers* given, regardless of votes.

Comment: Do you think "2" is the number of questions with positive votes?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a question is considered "answered" if and only if there is at least one answer with a score of 1 or more.  If there are answers, but none of them have a positive score then the site has determined that the question is still "unanswered" and visually indicates that in the manor you're describing to encourage people to go to that question and answer it, and to discourage people from going to that question to *find* an answer.